# Linq to SQL - Start Of month

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have an sql statement which returns me the 1st day of the month:

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @input), 0)
```

How would I recreate this call using SQLFunctions.DateAdd and SQLFunctions.DateDiff?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With [SQLFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) you won't go very far, considering that `Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that call functions in the database in **LINQ to Entities queries**.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var zero = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

var resxxxx = (from p in ctx.Addresses 
               select new { 
                          month = zero.AddMonths(SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth(zero, p.Date)) 
                          }
              ).FirstOrDefault();
```

The important part is `month = zero.AddMonths(SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth(zero, p.Date))`.

Note that I've used the `zero = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);`, but any 1st of the month would be ok (1st jan 1980, 1st jul 1983, 1st dec 2100...). It's the two `0`s in your SQL command. `p.Date` is the date of which you want to calculate the first of the month (so `@input`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am actually using the entity framework (so SqlMethods is not allowed). But I managed to work out the solution from your answer:

var zero = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
month = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month", SqlFunctions.DateDiff("month", zero,p), zero);